# xelatex font search path

Tags: fonts, xetex, polyglossia, search

I am using Linux Ubuntu, using Tex Live 2023. I have fonts in both directories `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` and in `/usr/share/texmf/fonts`.
But my xelatex installed in `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin` does not search fonts in `/usr/share/texmf`.
How can I tell latex or xelatex to search fonts in both directories? or I have to copy all of my `/usr/share/texmf` fonts into the `/usr/local` directory?
I did not find anything in `tlmgr` documentation.

Comment: Are you specifying fonts be filename or by fontname?

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide a minimal example showing us how you're specifying the font and the relevant lines from the log when it isn't found?

Comment: Are you trying to use opentype fonts or traditional TeX fonts from `/usr/share`? Can you access the fonts there in other (non-TeX) applications?